# How do you handle Nullable type with SqlDataRecord

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sqldatatypes

I am parsing XML (LINQ to XML) and I am using a nullable type (`int?` and `decimal?`) in cases where the element / attribute is empty.  However, when building my collection to pass to the DB (Using TVP) I don't know how to handle the cases where the value is actually null.  I can't pass a null into the SqlDataRecord SetInt32 or SetDecimal and I don't want to set to zero....I actually want it to be null.

Telling me no overload for `int`?

Count below is a nullable type (`int?` Count)

```
SqlDataRecord rec = new SqlDataRecord(
              new SqlMetaData("Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50),
              new SqlMetaData("Type", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50),
              new SqlMetaData("Count", SqlDbType.Int));

   rec.SetString(0, dm.Name);
   rec.SetString(1, dm.Type);
   rec.SetString(2, dm.Count);
```

Any ideas how to handle this without passing zero (maintaining the null)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Extension method:

```
static class SqlDataRecordExtensions
{
    static void SetNullableInt32(this SqlDataRecord rec, int index, Int32? value)
    {
        if (value.HasValue)
            rec.SetInt32(index, value.GetValueOrDefault());
        else
            rec.SetDBNull(index);
    }
}
```

or, to use `SetSqlInt32` as suggested by D Stanley:

```
static class SqlDataRecordExtensions
{
    static void SetNullableInt32(this SqlDataRecord rec, int index, Int32? value)
    {
        rec.SetSqlInt32(index, value.HasValue ? value.GetValueOrDefault() : SqlInt32.Null);
        //                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        //                                      You can leave out the cast to (SqlInt32),
        //                                      because the conversion is implicit
    }
}
```

Note, 9 Dec 2013: Returning to this answer because of a comment, I noticed a small opportunity for improvement, based on Eric Lippert's series on nullable micro-optimizations, which can be found at http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/20/nullable-micro-optimizations-part-one/.

In brief, while the `Value` property requires less typing and is therefore arguably more optimal for the programmer, it has to throw an exception if HasValue is false.  On the other hand, the `GetValueOrDefault()` method is a simple field access.  Because of this, `GetValueOrDefault()` requires fewer instructions and is more likely to be inlined, so it is more optimal for the compiler and the processor.

Comment: SetValue(ordinal,object) handles nullables and null values with a little bit of overhead for type and value length checking.  The performance difference may not be noticeable.

Comment: @RichardCollette Thanks for the comment; I didn't think of that.  I suspect you're right that the performance difference is probably insignificant for most applications.  I do tend to prefer stronger typing on philosophical grounds, though.  Your comment also inspires me to add a small optimization I didn't think of two years ago.

Comment: Not sure if the framework has changed but it's SetDBNull in version 4 (note the 'B' case).

Comment: @PhilCooper *What* is SetDBNull in version 4?  What 'B' case?

Comment: @phoog SetDbNull is SetDBNull see here: [SqlDataRecord.SetDBNull](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/Microsoft/SqlServer/Server/SqlDataRecord.cs,483)

Comment: @PhilCooper Aha, I see.  When you said 'B' case I thought you meant that there were several cases and that one of them was identifed with the letter 'B'.  So confused.  I've corrected the answer; thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Answer (score 4):

I've never worked with `SqlDataRecord`, but when using `DataTable` and `DataRow`, or when using parameterized queries, I specify `null` using [`DBNull.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx).

With `SqlDataRecord`, it looks like you can use the [`SetDBNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqldatarecord.setdbnull.aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

As @phoog recommended, extension methods for different types:

```
public static class ExtensionSqlDataRecord
{
    public static void SetDateTime(this SqlDataRecord record, int ordinal, DateTime? value)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            record.SetDateTime(ordinal, (DateTime)value);
        }
        else
        {
            record.SetDBNull(ordinal);
        }
    }

    public static void SetInt32(this SqlDataRecord record, int ordinal, int? value)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            record.SetInt32(ordinal, (int)value);
        }
        else
        {
            record.SetDBNull(ordinal);
        }
    }

    public static void SetByte(this SqlDataRecord record, int ordinal, byte? value)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            record.SetByte(ordinal, (byte)value);
        }
        else
        {
            record.SetDBNull(ordinal);
        }
    }

    public static void SetDecimal(this SqlDataRecord record, int ordinal, decimal? value)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            record.SetDecimal(ordinal, (decimal)value);
        }
        else
        {
            record.SetDBNull(ordinal);
        }
    }

    public static void SetBoolean(this SqlDataRecord record, int ordinal, bool? value)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            record.SetBoolean(ordinal, (bool)value);
        }
        else
        {
            record.SetDBNull(ordinal);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should use `SetSqlInt32` instead of `SetString`.  Try

```
rec.SetSqlInt32(2, (dm.Count.HasValue ? new SqlInt32(dm.Count) : SqlInt32.Null) );
```

Comment: That would have to be `rec.SetSqlInt32(2, (dm.Count.HasValue ? new SqlInt32(dm.Count.Value) : SqlInt32.Null) );`

Comment: Further, as I realized when editing my answer, the implicit conversion from int to SqlInt32 means you can do this: `rec.SetSqlInt32(2, dm.Count.HasValue ? dm.Count.Value : SqlInt32.Null);`

Answer (score 0):

//Ive found this to work the best for me when checking or dealing with nullable types 
  //in my example I am checking values stored in a String[] array

```
sqlcmdUpdateRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strSomeValue", (strRecord[(int) 
DataFields.SomeDataField] as object) ?? DBNull.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try the below.

```
if(dm.Count == null){
  rec.SetDBNull(2)
}
else{
 rec.SetString(2, dm.Count);
}
```