# Can I tell from a SqlMetaData instance whether the column is nullable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, t-sql

I'm looking at the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlmetadata(v=vs.110).aspx) and don't see a way to get whether the corresponding column accepts null values. Unless I'm missing something?

Example of a SqlMetaData instance in my Locals right now:

[image]

Comment: I don't know much about the C# aspect so I can't really answer your question, but if you have access to check the nullability of the column via SSMS I would compare the results of a nullable and nonnullable column to see if you can isolate a difference.

Comment: @AnthonyHancock I need to get it in C# land

Comment: I understand that, I was only suggesting that comparing both might help you find it in C# land to use going forward.

Comment: Based on the answers to this question, I would assume that you cannot determine nullability from the SQLMetaDataClass http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405320/how-do-you-handle-nullable-type-with-sqldatarecord

Comment: It has been a while since I did c# SQL stuff outside of ssis, but if you are looking at a connection to a table then yes, you should be able to see the meta data for the table which will include if it is nullable.  If you are pulling data and then look at the metadata for what you pulled, it will no longer show if it is nullable as that is a value of the column of the table, not of the data.